# QuickBlox iOS contact list : accept/reject subscription state

Tags: ios, quickblox

With reference to this link- http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Contact_list

I haven't found the `subscriptionState` property of `QBContactListItem`. If am adding a contact using

```
[[QBChat instance] addUserToContactListRequest:0123456];
```

I would like to follow the subscription state as `QBPresenseSubscriptionStateBoth`. I haven't found out a way to get these and implement it in my code. Please provide some light into this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly you would like to implement?

Use this method to add contact request

```
[[QBChat instance] addUserToContactListRequest:0123456];
```

Use this code to accept this requests

```
- (void)chatDidReceiveContactAddRequestFromUser:(NSUInteger)userID{
    [[QBChat instance] confirmAddContactRequest:userID];
}
```

Then, both users can get each other from contact list by

```
[QBChat instance].contactList.contacts
```

Comment: There was a subscription state in the documentation. I have referred QuickBlox API but it took me no where. Please look into this Igor :)

Comment: You mean you don't have access to subscription state in code, but there is info in documentation?

Comment: No Igor. There was documentation about those subscription states, but in the code I dont see them.

Comment: Yes @Xander is saying right i am also finding a way to set the subscription type both. It is not clearly documented in QuickBlox.